# Stopping specific file types from being created

Tags: usb, security, file-permissions, virus, virus-removal

I got infected with the shortcut virus for the second time. In short, my question is: can I stop *.inf files from being created on a specific external drive(USB)? Maybe some drive settings or a program.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think so, because the "script" would have to cover many different apps that all write to wherever. Why not keep a live AV scanner always on (like Windows Defender).